# Impossible to make Vertical ProgressBar bigger

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to display a vertical ProgressBar.
I've started to use VerticalProgressBar from this GitHub : https://github.com/halzhang/Android-VerticalProgressBar

But this solution doesn't work on one of test devices, and only on one. The bar doesn't display the progress.

So, I've just simply create a basic ProgressBar and rotate it :

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_time_remaining"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:max="1005"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:indeterminate="false"/>
```

[image: Vertical ProgressBar]

This work perfectly... but my needs are really precise.
When I do so, the progress isn't display on all the height of the component, but only of a fixed % of the height as you can see on the screen above. I've found that this % is fixed by the width of the component, it's why the component is set with a 'match_parent' width.

This condition isn't annoying when it's horizontal, because the width indicate the size of the progress you want..
I need it to fit the entire screen, and I can't set a bigger height/width, as it is in 'match_parent'.

Also, as you can see, there is no padding, margin, or anything else..

Does someone have any tip to make the ProgressBar fit exactly the height of the screen, so make it bigger than it actually has ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**

The ProgressBar is a direct child of the main RelativeLayout of the activity.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `com.halzhang.android.verticalprogressbar.VerticalSeekBar` instead of `ProgressBar` in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following in the corresponding onCreate() Method:

```
LayoutParams params = null;
ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
Map<String, Integer> map = deriveMetrics2(this);
params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 20; //use appropriate value here. 
params.width = map.get("screenHeight");
progress.setLayoutParams(params);

public Map<String, Integer> deriveMetrics(Activity activity) {
    try {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        if (activity != null) {
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        }

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("screenWidth", Integer.valueOf(metrics.widthPixels));
        map.put("screenHeight", Integer.valueOf(metrics.heightPixels));
        map.put("screenDensity", Integer.valueOf(metrics.densityDpi));

        return map;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        ; // just use zero values
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. Of course declare the function outside onCreate...

Comment: Thanks, but that don't work. The height of the progress is again dependent of the width, so the only thing that make some changes is to modify the params.width value...

Comment: Yeah, I've already tested it.. I've tested with params.width = map.get("screenHeight"); and with 1500... Nothing is working, the Progress height is fixed at the equivalent of the width of the screen, regardless of which width I specify..

Comment: Does they height change when you set the width in dp in your xml file?

Comment: Yes, it change, but only until the width I specify reach the width of the screen, after, it completly ignore the width I set, and is still blocked by the width of the screen. For exemple, if I set width=200dp, the progress will be 200dp height. But if I set 1500dp, the height is blocked on ~310dp (width of my screen)...